# How to display an image stored in postgres as bytea to client through Nodejs/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, bytea

Im trying to display an image that already save in postgres in a column bytea type... and i try everything, modify server or modify client and nothing get results.

What is the right way to retrieve data from postgres and send it to client using nodejs/express?

This is my server code:
(doesnt matter if i use res.send or res.end or if i transform the image to base64 string)
[server code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGq5N.png)

### solutions that i tried:

```
 static async getImagen(req, res) {
        const nombre = req.params.nombre
        try{
            const result = await ImagenModel.getImagen()
            if (result.length > 0){
                res.contentType('image/png')
                res.send(result[0].imagen)   
                return
            }

            res.status(400).json({message: "No hay registros"})
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e)
            res.status(500).json({message: "Algo ha salido mal"})
        }
    }
```

im always get the same response:
[response in client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1yX3.png)

the same problem for fetch api (nothing happen, not changes)
[fetch api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBEmL.png)

```
const img = document.getElementById("img")
const uri = 'http://localhost:3000/imagen/imagen'

fetch(uri).then(res => res.blob())
.then(data => {
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(data)
})
```

[image type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPmWS.png)
display image on client

Comment: Where's the postgres in your code? What is `ImagenModel.getImagen()` doing?

Comment: So what kind of image is it? You use jpg in the path name and png in the mime type.

Comment: *ImagenModel.getImagen()*  this returns a row from postgres

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code of that. What is the type of `result[0].imagen`?

Comment: The image is png, the path that ends in jpg is the route

Comment: the way the model access to postgres doesnt matter, the return is an object type buffer like
{
  imagen: <Buffer 7b 22 6e 61 6d 65 22 3a 22 63 6c 61 73 69 66 69 63 61 63 69 6f 6e 65 73 2e 70 6e 67 22 2c 22 64 61 74 61 22 3a 7b 22 74 79 
70 65 22 3a 22 42 75 66 66 ... 391258 more bytes>
}

Comment: Well [that ain't no png file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG#File_header)

Comment: I dont got it, what mean "no png file" ?

Comment: A PNG file always begins with the bytes `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a`. I don't know what you have in that buffer, but it's not a png image - which is the reason it cannot get displayed in your browser

Comment: It is a png without a doubt, is a screenshot from windows screenshot tool

Comment: data:{type: 'Buffer', data: Array(110445)}
encoding:"7bit"
md5: "029f1210d61ebc539f9fb99481a15b0e"
mimetype:"image/png"
name:"clasificaciones.png"
size:110445
tempFilePath:""
truncated:false
[[Prototype]]: Object,

If i use fetch api and json converter to print to console

Comment: Uh right. It's a JSON file! Not a png. why did you use a json converted when you wanted to store a screenshot as a `bytea` blob??? For some reason you stored json text in your database instead. Fix that, and your code to serve the image will work.